# Angular $scope does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs-scope, this

I'm using AngularJS 1.3.3 and jQuery 1.11.1.

The following does not bind properly to an ng-repeat (meaning it doesn't bind the DOM to the data or update when the data is updated):

```
var aliasApp = angular.module('aliasApp', ['ngSanitize']);
aliasApp.controller('AliasController', function($scope) {
    $scope.aliases = new Array();
    $scope.setAliases = function(v){
        var a = new Array();
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(v) === '[object Array]') {
            for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
                a.push(new Alias(v[i]));
            }
            $scope.aliases = a;
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the BROKEN code in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f6njo7sq/

However, putting "aliases" onto the "this" scope does work.

```
var aliasApp = angular.module('aliasApp', ['ngSanitize']);
aliasApp.controller('AliasController', function($scope) {
    var self = this;
    self.aliases = new Array();
    $scope.setAliases = function(v){
        var a = new Array();
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(v) === '[object Array]') {
            for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
                a.push(new Alias(v[i]));
            }
            self.aliases = a;
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the WORKING code in JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/86wduo52/

Does anyone know why the second one works but the first does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is everything to do with how you are approaching $scope.

The JS code you posted is fine. It's your HTML code thats broken.

```
ng-repeat="alias in root.aliases"
```

is wrong, instead try

```
ng-repeat="alias in aliases"
```

This is because you were looking in the "wrong" scope, the 2nd piece of JS code however changed what $scope your aliases object was in, and instead placed it in the root scope.

Comment: Cooool!  Soooo... why does everyone recommend giving a name to your controller if it secretly rescopes/breaks things?  i.e. ng-controller="AliasController as root"

Comment: Also, if you have a chance, could you update your answer with a link to a working JSFiddle that DOES use "controller as ctrl... repeat ctrl.list" correctly?  All the documentation I can find says that "controller as..." works with all the ng directives, and yet this very much proves that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
aliasApp.controller('AliasController', function($scope) {
    $scope.aliases = new Array();
    var  sc = $scope;
    $scope.setAliases = function(v){
        var a = new Array();
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(v) === '[object Array]') {
            for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
                a.push(new Alias(v[i]));
            }
            sc.aliases = a;
            sc.$apply();
        }
    }
});
```

Lets see if this works then, it will lead us to something I think.

Comment: Thank you for the idea -- but that doesn't change anything (my fiddle WORKS with or without your line added).  The top snippet is the one that SHOULD work according to all of the documentation.  I'll add a new fiddle with the top snippet.

Comment: Tried cleaning array, instead of assigning new value? Look at example.

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the things I tried too -- the way I did it was:
arr.length = 0;
for...
  arr.push(...);
end for

Comment: The simplest way to test that is to go to the broken fiddle and replace "a.push(...)" with "$scope.aliases.push(...)" then delete the $scope.aliases = a; line.  And no beans.

Comment: BTW -- I thought for sure that your code (above) would work when I was researching a couple days ago.  According to all of the documentation it SHOULD work.  But it doesn't and I have no idea why...